# Populate fields x,y or long, lat, depending on input data, and create a point based on input

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, postgis

I have a table created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE public."EESsite" (
   "ID" integer NOT NULL,
   "Name" character varying(254),
   "LatitudeDe" double precision,
   "Longitud_1" double precision,
   "Easting" double precision,
   "Northing" double precision,
   geom geometry(Point,32636),
    CONSTRAINT "PrimaryKey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"))
      WITH (
      OIDS=FALSE
      );
ALTER TABLE public."EESsite"
```

What I want to do is to populate either Longitud_1,LatitudeDE, or Easting ,Northing, depending on the input data. For example, sometimes I have teh coordinates in LonLat format, but sometimes I have them is UTM, but I need both in my columns. From each pair of coordinates I want to create a point using a function and a trigger. I have been able to produce the point automatically and extract the coordinates from geom to put them into the columns, but I have not been able to  do it programmatically. I have tried this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_latlon_column() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $BODY$
   BEGIN
    IF NEW."Longitud_1" IS NULL THEN
    NEW.geom =(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(NEW."Longitud_1"::float8,NEW."LatitudeDe"::float8),4326),32636));
    end if;
    IF NEW."Easting" IS NULL THEN
    NEW.geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(NEW."Easting"::float8, NEW."Northing"::float8), 32636),
    NEW.Longitud_1 = (ST_SetSRID(ST_Y(geom),32636),4326),
    NEW.LatitudeDe = (ST_SetSRID(ST_X(geom),32636),4326);
    end if;
   RETURN new;
   END;
  $BODY$
 language plpgsql;


 CREATE TRIGGER update_geom
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON public."EESsite"
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE  update_latlon_column();
```

I can create both the function and the trigger, but whenever I try to add a new row I run into this problem:

> ERROR: record "new" has no field "longitud_1"

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Dont use mixed cased identifiers (or: you are doomed to doublequote them)

Comment: Thank you @wildplasser! I did solve it just by changing the names :D

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem after following [wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905902/wildplasser) suggestion to refrain myself of using a mixed cased identifier. I double-checked my code —it had other major issues— and after some trials finally made my script to work. If you have any suggestion to improve it, would be more than appreciated. Right now, this code works like this:

> If I fill a field and write the LonLat coordinates (EPSG:4326; but you
>   can change it of course), it will use these coordinates to populate
>   the geom as a UTM (EPSG:32636) point, and then will populate the field
>   Easting and Northing with the proper coordinates. It works the other
>   way around, if you fill the Easting and Northing, it will create a
>   point in geom and then populate latitude and longitude.

Nevertheless, and this is where you can improve it, it will no update any column if you change any of these values. I hope you find it useful, though.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_latlon_column()
  RETURNS trigger AS
  $BODY$BEGIN

IF NEW.longitude IS NOT NULL THEN
        NEW.geom = (ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(NEW.longitude::float8,NEW.latitude::float8),4326),32636));
        NEW.easting = (ST_X(NEW.geom));
        NEW.northing = (ST_Y(NEW.geom));
  ELSIF NEW.easting IS NOT NULL THEN
        NEW.geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(NEW."easting"::float8,NEW."northing"::float8), 32636);
        NEW.longitude = (ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID((NEW.geom),32636),4326)));
        NEW.latitude = (ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID((NEW.geom),32636),4326)));
   END IF;

  RETURN new;
  END;
  $BODY$
language plpgsql;
```